# How to add integers in different methods

Tags: c#, methods, static, integer, void

I'm very new to C# and have a very limited understanding of the "proper code" to use. I had the goal to imitate the old Pokemon battle systems as best I could with what I know and am having a hard time linking a stored **int** value for **HP** between two methods (assuming that's the right word), to calculate new Hp when the second method interacts with the main method. Had a hard time finding an answer for that in searches so here is the code:

```
" static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random Gen = new Random();

            int enemyhealth = (150);
            int playerhealth = (100); //the line i need to use
            int edefense = (20);
            int pattack = (30);
            int rate = Gen.Next(1,5);
            int critical = 0;                   "


 static void enemyattack()
        {
            Random Gen1 = new Random();

            int pdefense = (20);
            int eattack = (20);
            int erate = Gen1.Next(1, 5);
            int ratattack = Gen1.Next(1,3);
            int critical1 = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("Enemy Ratta gets ready!");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("\nEnemy Ratta attacks!\n");
            Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------------------------");

            ratattack = Gen1.Next(1,3);
            if (ratattack = 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enemy Ratta used Tail Whip!");
                pdefense = (pdefense - erate);
                Console.ReadKey();
                Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                erate = Gen1.Next(1, 5);
                if (erate <= 3)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nIt wasn't very effective!");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nIt was super effective!");
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Squirtle's Defense decreased by " + erate + "");
                Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            }
            else if (ratattack == 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nRatta used Tackle");
                erate = Gen1.Next(1, 5);
                if (erate >= 5)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("\nCRITICAL HIT!!!!");
                    Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    Console.WriteLine("It was super effective!");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    eattack = eattack + 10;
                }
                else
                {
                    critical1 = Gen1.Next(1, 5);
                    eattack = critical1 + eattack;
                }
                phealth = Math.Abs((eattack - pdefense) - playerhealth);    ***//This Line is where I'm having trouble because phealth is used in my first method as a stored integer and the new calculation for phealth won't interact with the phealth in the origional main, i simply belive I haven't learned that part of c#, I only have 5 hours of youtube tutorials.***
                Console.WriteLine("Ratta dealt " + Math.Abs(eattack - pdefense) + " damage!");
                eattack = 30;
                Console.WriteLine("\n----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                Console.ReadKey();

                Console.ReadKey();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't have methods inside the `Main` method. Or is that a formatting glitch?

Comment: Assuming you mean the way the code is written, I didn't place the entire code to make it easier to read, this is my first post so I'm still cautious of what's allowed. It is all organized properly in separate methods to where I've been able to test the program. If it would help I can post the entire code.

Comment: You need to include the line of code where `phealth` is declared, because that's relevant to the question; right now it's not clear why your code isn't working the way you want it to. What you should try to do is post a *minimal* piece of code that demonstrates your problem (for example, all the `Console.WriteLine` lines are irrelevant to your question.

Comment: I see, it's a formatting problem then. There is simpler way to just use a global variable (declared outside the method) and be done with it. But I recommend creating a new class and using objects to access said values

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) from the help center.

Answer (score 0):

Make Static method , or simply add your variable in the main Class (where Main method Stored) 
Here example

```
class Program
{
int HP;

int Main()
{
HP=0; //Now you HP is 0;
Method();

}

void Method()
{
HP+=50; //Now you HP is 50 
}
```

}

Comment: I made in hp global with  class Program
    {
    int playerhealth = 100;

Comment: Your int playerhealth located in Main() method Variables in method available only in METHOD! move your int playerhealth in class, and in method remove keyword int

Comment: Sorry if I missed something i'm having issues with posting. I made the integer for hp global removing all the initial values set in under the different methods . I'm having an error throughout the program saying an object reference is required for all the processes that use the integer, what would be the best way to call anything. Primarily this line :                                                                                     phealth = Math.Abs((eattack - pdefense) - playerhealth);

Comment: Alexandr Sargsyan--Is there another way to send the code asside from comments?

Comment: In this page no. Can you paste it here?

Comment: As a comment it's too long about 7k characters? I'm a bit confused how to send the code at this point, fairly new to the site.

Comment: ok , Take it ;) http://textuploader.com/atrbj    /// I add static keyword before int playerhealth, and remove initializing in class field, members should be initialized in method, read more about OOP ))

Comment: Ha, thanks a ton man. Actually wasn't to sure of the right way to globalize things and have just recently start working outside of one core main build. I set the value to the "static int hp" and deleted it under all the methods and the program calculates the global processes. Appreciate all the advice.

Answer (score 0):

I would break things down into separate classes. For example you should have a Player class that contains all the information for the player. You can't have methods like that in your main program. You need to keep everything separate. Make a class for each object you need.

```
public class Player
{
 int currentHp = 100;
 int maxHp = 100;
 int atkPower = 20;
 int defense = 20;
 string playerName = "Ashe"

 public Player() {}
 public void TakeDamage(int damage)
 {
  currentHp = currentHp - damage;
 }

}

public class Enemy
{
 int currentHp = 100;
 int maxHp = 100;
 int atkPower = 20;
 int defense = 20;
 string enemyName= "Rattata"

 public Enemy(){}

 public int AttackPlayer(Player player)
 {
   // all of your attack logic, pass in the player here
   player.TakeDamage(someAmountofDamage);
 }
}
```

Then in your main program:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             Player myPlayer = new Player();
             Enemy myEnemy = new Enemy();

             myEnemy.AttackPlayer(player);
        }
```

Comment: As a new programmer one of the first things you should do, in my opinion, is try to break things down into logical chunks. It then becomes much easier to ask for help. Asking the right questions is very important as a programmer.